# Can you skip dialogues in Cave Story?

Tags: cave-story

I am playing Cave Story on hard. I don't find it too difficult, but I would like to be able to replay some segments of the game more quickly. Especially boss fights work on my nerves sometimes, as they are introduced with quite long dialogues.

Pressing <kbd>z</kbd> makes the dialogues scroll by faster, but you can't entirely skip them. Is there any way to skip dialogues entirely?

Comment: Well, the simple answer seems to be "No". :-( Either way, managed to finish yet another boss by watching a cutscene 10 times. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no.

Both Cave Story and Cave Story+ actually attempt to make this more bearable. If you've already sat through a dialog segment and died, the dialog will appear much faster the second time — i.e., box by box instead of scrolling text. These can be skipped through relatively quickly by hammering <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Skipping these sequences entirely does not seem to be possible, however.

Comment: Although, there are certain pre-boss cutscenes that can be skipped through quite quickly after the first time. I'm not sure if this is just the final (non-secret) boss or whether it happens elsewhere too. Pressing Z makes the whole text bubble get displayed and skipped instead of just scrolling fast in these cases.

Comment: @RHINO_Mk.II I am currently stuck on Toroko+ and this is the case, however adding up all the cutscene animations (which are not sped up) the cutscene is still a nearly unbearable 30 seconds. :(

Comment: On my first playthrough of Cave Story I was stuck on Monster X for hours - and had to clear half a labyrinth level of bugs before fighting him each time.

Comment: It is super annoying that you cannot save right before Monster X. Friggin' bugs.

Answer (score 2):

**The v1.1 update (Aug 3, 2017) to Cave Story+ on Switch added an option to skip cutscenes by holding X.**

Holding down X during any dialogue scene will cause the game to run in a fast-forward mode. This will speed up all dialogue and animations with an increased framerate.

Currently the option to skip cutscenes is only available on Cave Story+ for Switch. It is unknown if Nicalis plans to bring this feature to other platforms.

**Sources**

- Reddit: [Cave Story Switch Cutscene "Skip" Added in Latest Patch through Uncapped FPS](https://www.reddit.com/r/cavestory/comments/6rmuw1/cave_story_switch_cutscene_skip_added_in_latest/)
- Perfectly Nintendo: [Cave Story+: Software updates](http://www.perfectly-nintendo.com/cave-story-software-updates-latest-update-patch-1/)